# Variable grid size for matlab imagesc() plot

Tags: matlab, plot, grid

I have data of a heated plate (2m x 2m = L x L) defined by a grid (x- and y-coordinates from 0 to 2 in same or different refinements) and a corresponding matrix containing the temperatures of the centres of the plates fields (the field dimensions are defined by the x- and y-grid).

The imagesc() plot function from matlab creates good results on equidistant grids since every field has the same length and width. However working with an non-equidistant grid requires to adjust all fields dimensions according to x-y-grid.

Is it possible to do this within the imagesc() function?

Code:

```
imagesc(x,y, sol)
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
colormap(jet(2000)); colorbar;
xlabel('x[m]')
ylabel('y[m]')
```

x and y are vectors containing the coordinates of the grid, sol is the matrix containing the field centres temperatures.

Plot:

[Heated Plate with equidistant grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub0Tr.jpg)

[Heated Plate with non-equidistant grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgTLF.jpg)

The non-equidistant grid performs a refinement on the right side of the plate since numerical error is biggest there.
The refinement is defined by

- same discretization for 0 <= x <= L/2 (same for y)
- double fine discretization for L/2 <= x <= L*3/4 (same for y)
- four times discretization for L*3/4 <= x <= L (same for y)

As you can see, the refinement's new field dimensions are not considered which ends up ruining the visulization.

I've already tried different plot methods like surf or pcolor. Both are not well suited for a field-centre-oriented solution.

Thank's for any advice.

Comment: Please don't call them cells, as that's [a very specific function/data storage type](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) in MATLAB and the way you use it here is highly confusing.

Comment: Thank's, it's changed to field. I hope it'll be clear what's meant by field in this context.

Comment: Sorry I probably explained it bad, what I want is to plot the solution on a grid which corresponds to the refinements made on the non-equidistant grid. Meaning the 'fields' shall not be the same length and width for the area 0 <= x <= L/2 (same for y) as for L/2 <= x <= L*3/4 (same for y).

Comment: "imagesc(x,y,C) specifies the image location. Use x and y to specify the locations of the corners corresponding to C(1,1) and C(m,n). To specify both corners, set x and y as two-element vectors. To specify the first corner and let imagesc determine the other, set x and y as scalar values. The image is stretched and oriented as applicable."

Comment: I've been trying your approach without success. Can't find a work around.

Comment: Well, `imagesc()` is a rather "stupid" low-level function for displaying images. In images all pixels have the same size. If yours don't, then you'd either need to interpolate to a full high-res grid, or use more advanced plotting functions like `surf()`.

Comment: Yup, but it's actually quite straight forward for the equidistant grid. If they would be a way to manipulate the pixel size of the image, i.e. to create effects, it would be really efficient way to plot my solution. 
Maybe someone else does know a way. Until than I'll go with the patch function.

Comment: Use surf and meshgrid to write a function that does what you want.